# Django UnboundLocalError at /x/ when surfing to localhost:8000/x

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

I am new to Django, I just created a model with few classes, and created views and urls and everything works just fine up until I try to extract the id of an object to use it in the url. Here are my codes:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # / structures/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # / structures/712
    url(r'^(?P<structure_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Structure

def index(request):
    all_structures = Structure.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for Structure in all_structures:
        url = '/structures/' + str(Structure.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + Structure.name + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)

def detail(request, structure_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Structure id " + str(structure_id) + "</h2>")
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Structure(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Type(models.Model):
    typename = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.typename

class Record(models.Model):
    structure = models.ForeignKey(Structure, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #each structure has many records, each per line
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    pos = models.IntegerField()
    long = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is the error I a having:

[image: 1]

I am not seeing any wrong referencing or any issue with my code. I am also watching "thenewboston" tutorial and I am doing the exact same steps as Bucky. It works just fine for him, but not me.

Thank's for helping me out!

Comment: `for Structure in all_structures:`  this variable name collides with the class that you are importing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the class name `Structure` as variable for the forloop.  use `structure`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sandeep!! I totally missed that one!